# CSS and Sprites for standard buttons

Tags: css, html, button, sprite

I want to use a standard set of buttons on a website regardless of what is written in them (i.e. submit, pay, go, spell correct) but for some reason I can not get the sprite image to show up.  My codes is as follows:
HTML:

```
    <div id="iconic">
    Place Sprite button here <span><a class="button" href="#">Test</a></span>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
    span.iconic a:link
    span.iconic a:visited
    {
    display: block;
background-image:url('images/an_nav_btn.jpg');
width: 150px;
height: 45px;
    }
    span.iconic a:hover
    {
background-position: 0 -50px;
}
    span.iconica a:active
    {
background-position: 0 -100px;
}
```

Any suggestions on how to get this to display with the text on top (in this case it will have the button with the word "test" on it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: new code:<br/>
<br/>
CSS:<br/>
<br/>
    #iconic span a:link
    #iconic span a:visited
    {
    display: block;
    background-image:url('images/an_nav_btn.jpg');
    width: 150px;
    height: 45px;
        }
    #iconic span a:hover{
    background-position: 0 -50px;
    }
    #iconic span a:active{
    background-position: 0 -100px;
<br/>         }
HTML:<br/>
    <div id='iconic'>
    Place Sprite button here <span><a href="#">Test</a></span>
    </div>

Comment: Sorry for some reason I can not get this to format the code correctly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to your posted css you are attempting to manipulate a link inside a span with the class of "iconic"... and that doesn't work with what you have in the html:

to get you on the right track, try 
replacing all the `span.iconic`'s
with `#iconic span`'s

`#iconic span a` translates to "all `<a>`'s inside a `<span>` inside any element with the id of 'iconic' "

Comment: I have cleaned up the code based on the two suggestions but the image is not showing up.

Comment: @user2909044 check your image address.... i used your code to create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/80PoundsOfFury/36TgC/1/) and everything looks dandy. i had to use my own image though

Comment: That was it, my CSS is in a separate folder, I was basing the path of the image from the location of the web page, not the CSS.

Answer (score 0):

In CSS:

`.` is used for to prefix class names

`#` is used to prefix IDs.

Your element is a `DIV`, and you're specifying a `SPAN` in your CSS. You've got both of these mixed up.

The CSS declaration for `<div id="iconic">`

would be:

```
#iconic {
    ...
}
```

You may want to consider looking at [Font Awesome](http://fontawesome.io/), that handles a lot of this for you.

Comment: Doh... I had it that way then was testing and forgot to set it back when I posted it.